# Prometheus - shorten a label

Tags: prometheus

I want to shorten a label to a certain amount of characters using the label_replace function. I already tried the following to take the first 12 characters of the entityName label and move them to the id label:

entityName label:

```
45b6100b82fd64f060494b37adde8fab4ab5f2c6a7533f0587556cb73b6ef00c@processor
```

Query:

```
label_replace(vector, "id", "${1}", "entityName", "(.{12})"))
```

The quantifier `.{12}` does not seem to work whereas `.+` works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why your regex isn't working, every example I find online shows it's correct for me but I'm no regex expert. Either way, I had a look into this to see if I could get the information as you explained, unfortunately I couldn't. The best I could come up with is the below:

```
^(.*).{41}
```

But this is only useful if each one is exactly the same length of characters as it strips the last 41 characters, for your example listed I believe it would be 63?